# Particle settings emit soft body object animation

Tags: animation

I am trying to make this can shoot out worms at frame 35, then the worms fall to the ground and squish. It works perfectly when I make just the emitter object and the plane, and then as soon as I add it to a particle settings object group, it

1. doesnt reach all the way to the ground
2. doesnt settle on the ground but flies around crazy

I just want the simple movement of them falling and crashing to the plane but in like a random shooting motion like it is being squirted from the top.

If anyone knows anything that could help it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!